# Codeigniter stopped sending mails from gmail smtp on wamp server windows 10

Tags: smtp, gmail, windows-10, wamp, codeigniter-2

The code i am posting was working fine for 2 months. Now, from some reason it stopped sending mails.

```
$config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'system@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
            );
$this->load->library('email', $config);

//za da mi ispraka na sevisniot mail i da mozam da sledam dali ispraka izvestai dokolku oni stiklirale isprakanje
$this->email->clear(TRUE);  //za reset pred sekoe novo prakanje od jamkata
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('doNotReply', '');
$this->email->to('service@gmail.com'); 

$this->email->subject($subjectStart . ' izvestaj');
$this->email->message('');  
$this->email->attach('D:/wamp64/www/dica/assets/iEksel/'. $filename);
if ( ! $this->email->send()){

    $myfile = fopen("mail.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt =  $this->email->print_debugger(); 
    fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
    fclose($myfile);

}
```

The debugger outputs this errors:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
> Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
> Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
> Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:< doNotReply >
> < pre>from: The following SMTP error was encountered: < br />Unable to send data: RCPT TO:< br />< pre>to: < /pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: < br />Unable to send data: DATA< br />< pre >data: The following SMTP error was encountered: < br />Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter.
>
> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Does anyone has an idea why this code that worked perfectly for 2 months, now fails to work?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this smtp code for server-side.
for server-side this much code is enough:

```
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('emailtxt'));
        $this->email->cc($this->input->post('cctxt'));
        $this->email->from($fromEmail['user_email']);
        $this->email->subject($this->input->post('smailtxt'));
        $this->email->message($this->input->post('tamailtxt'));
        $this->email->attach($pathfile);
        $this->email->send();
```

and for client side the code you used looks find. Issue must be if smtp user email and password is changed or check php.ini file in wamp.

Comment: This is what i have in php.ini, is this ok?:

SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

Comment: it should be like this: SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = something@exmple.com
sendmail_path = "\"E:\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" and in sendmail/sendmail.ini file is like this: smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com smtp_port=465 smtp_ssl=auto force_sender=something@example.com

Comment: But previosly, i did not change anything in php.ini. I did all the configuration from codeigniter like i previosly explained. So how come this stopped working after 2 months of successfull work?

Comment: I also noticed that no matter what values i write about :
'smtp_user' => 'system@gmail.com'
and 
 'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
i still get the same error.

Comment: from above change in localhost it is working. This change must required.

Comment: smtp user means form this user mail is going to sent.

Comment: I have tried your proposition and it still does not work. Did google change something, or the OS windows 10 becaucse the above code was working just for 2 months till now?

Comment: everything works fine again, without any changes in my code, if you use yahoo mail.
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'

This seems to be gmail related problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of smtp used smtps in array.

```
$config = Array(
 'protocol' => 'smtps',
 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
 'smtp_port' => 465,
 'smtp_user' => 'system@gmail.com',
 'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
 'mailtype'  => 'html', 
 'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```